# How can we write mongo db query in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb

I have a *Feed* collection that has two fields: `username` and `sentiment`.  I have to write a aggregation in *spring* to group by `username` and `sentiment`. I also have to display total number of times `username` comes in collection.

How to do that?

My code is:

```
db.feed.aggregate([
{$group: {_id : {username : '$username',sentiment:'$sentiment'}, total:{$sum             :1}}},
{$project : {username : '$_id.username', sentiment : '$_id.sentiment', total :                     '$total', _id : 0}}
])
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a Spring Data Mongo solution? Or are you using some other non-Spring Mongo library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing that comes to mind:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation

So in your case it would look something like:

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

class Stat {
   String username;
   String sentiment;
   int total;
}

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    group("username", "sentiment").count().as("total"),
    project().
       and("_id.username").as("username").
       and("_id.sentiment").as("sentiment").
       and("total").as("total")
);

AggregationResults<Stat> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "feed", Stat.class);
List<Stat> mappedResult = results.getMappedResults();
```